# refresh notes uiview from web

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

A Lotus notes doucment is oepned in browser from a notes view. This is opened using xpage and after save and exit like to automatically refresh uiview to show the back end changes.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

The application is running on 8.5.2 client and only few documents are opened in browser.

Comment: How is the document opened? In a new window/tab?

Comment: Is it Notes browser, external browser or do you mean XPiNC (XPage in Notes Client)?

Comment: Its notes browser, opened in new tab.

Comment: Then as far as I know it's not possible but I could be wrong...

Comment: Btw. you may want to edit your question and add the additional info there to make it clearer.

Comment: Is XPiNC not working for you in this case and that's why you open it in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your Save action **could** call (backend) view.refresh() method, but it is not recommended. This can lead to serious performance problems (semaphore locks on all http threads).

Comment: Need to refresh front end view (uiview) from where the xpage was opened in browser, so user see the changes in the view without having to press F9.

Answer (score 0):

As sais in one of your comments it is opened by a new tab. In fact that makes it a bit easier. When you can create a client side action that mimics the opening of the document by just calling window.open() you can call its parent ( the page you're window.open originated from) to do something.

something like window.opener.document.getElementById() 
( you have to google yourself for the correct syntax ).

This would give you the opportunity to call a partialrefresh on your view just before the child browser window is being closed.